# Azure app service app settings in the portal are not overriding appsettings.json values

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have the following in Startup (asp.net core 2.2 proj):

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
 {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;

        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
 }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings();

        Configuration.Bind("appSettings", appSettings);

        services.AddSingleton(appSettings);

        ....
}
```

I've set values to override all my app setting values in appsettings.json, but my app service is still using what is in appsettings instead of what I put in the portal.  Per the documentation, those portal app settings for the app service should override the appsettings.json file and get used instead.  Am I missing a step?

Thanks

Edit:

Even changing Startup to the following doesn't pick up my azure app settings:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;

        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddConfiguration(configuration)
            .SetBasePath(Environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
```

Comment: You're not assigning the result of your instantiation and construction of `ConfigurationBuilder`.

Comment: What do I assign it to?  The Configuration property?  ...instead of the IConfiguration object that gets passed in?  Thanks!

Comment: I changed it, please see my edit above, but that doesn't seem to do anything....it's still not loading my app settings from the azure app service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to get Appsettings on portal you need to use like `AppSettings:Hello` to reference variable names inside complex structures in `appsettings.*.json` files. Refer to this [article](https://blog.elmah.io/configuration-with-azure-app-services-and-aspnetcore/). The following is steps you could refer.

HomeController:

```
private AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    AppSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = AppSettings.Hello;
    return View();
}
```

AppSettings.cs:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddConfiguration(configuration)
        .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Hello": "world"
}
```

On portal:

[image]

And the output:

[image]

Comment: So really just adding "Appsettings:" before my settings name is what fixed it.  I did add the  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true) call anyway after that just to make sure that's in there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Windows** and **Linux** containers are a bit different.

For the following settings:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Hello": "world"
}
```

**Windows key:** `AppSettings:Hello`

**Linux key:**   `AppSettings__Hello`

Comment: Does it have to be named AppSettings as the root of the appsettings.json? If I use a custom name like "WeatherApi": { "Hello": "world" } and then in App Service Configuration use WeatherApi__Hello it doesn't override the value. But having AppSettings name bot in appsettings.json and using AppSettings__Hello seems to work.

Comment: You can make as many files of whatever name you like and add them to the configuration at startup. I'm not sure if that is what you're asking.